# forfiles and copy command with 'c' parameter

Tags: batch-file, cmd

So, im making this batch file to copy any mp4 file above 1gb to the current folder where the batch file if placed, but the copy command isnt working... where am i making mistakes?

```
    @echo off
    cd c:\

    forfiles /s /m *.mp4 /c "cmd /c if @fsize gtr 1000000000 copy @path  %~dp0"
    pause
```

Comment: Is an error being shown?

Comment: Change `copy @path  %~dp0` to `copy @path  0x22%~dp00x22`...

Comment: You could just use a normal `FOR` command with the `/R` option.  This would be much faster than using `FORFILES` with `CMD.exe`. I hope your batch file is not on the C: drive.

Answer (score 0):

An example using the 'speedier' for loop method:

```bat
@ECHO OFF
SET "Parent=%USERPROFILE%\Videos"
IF /I NOT "%CD%\"=="%~dp0" PUSHD "%~dp0"
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
IF /I NOT "!CD:%Parent%=!"=="%CD%" EXIT/B 
SETLOCAL DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /F "TOKENS=1,3*" %%A IN ('WHERE/T /R "%Parent%" *.mp4'
    ) DO IF %%A GTR 1000000000 COPY "%%C"
```

Comment: Would be interesting to do speed tests on `FOR /R`  `DIR /S` and `WHERE  /R` to see if there is a definitive speed advantage with any of them.

Comment: I've never been one for speed testing, but it has always felt to me as if **where** is quicker than **dir**. Add to that it appears to always provide file sizes without separators so is worth the risk over plain **For /R** using the **~z** substitution.